# Can I use sockets on Appengine without a special lib?

Tags: sockets, google-app-engine, go

I'm confused by the GAE [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/sockets/). It says  `App Engine supports sockets without requiring you to import any special App Engine libraries or add any special App Engine code`. but it seems misleading as just above it says `App Engine supports outbound sockets through the appengine/socket package.`

I would like to connect to an [IMAP](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap) server using the standard net package. Is that possible or I'm stuck with the GAE sockets API?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/sockets/

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to open an outbound socket without going through the appengine/socket api. This is because it works through RPC and an appengine.Context is needed to do that. You can still use the IMAP library you linked, though, as it provides a function to create a client with a given net.Conn. You can get a net.Conn from appengine/socket and pass it to NewClient to do your business. The reason it works on python and java is because they both use thread local memory to manage request state implicitly, whereas the go runtime does not.

Comment: Shortly said there is a documentation bug.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stops you from connecting to an Imap server, since you will initiate an outbound connection. For java, the standard java mail packages work out of the box.
Only for paid apps though, i.e. you need to have billing enabled.

Comment: My question is why would I need the appengine/sockets lib if no lib is required ? Makes sense?

Comment: Sending documentation feedback bug report... ok, done.  I think this might be a copy-and-paste typo, as the Java and Python docs have the exact same phrase, and in their cases, it's true.  :P  But given that the golang support for this API is in preview, it might be changed so that it too doesn't need appengine/sockets.  You can see this at the very end of the docs for the **Managed VM** version in: https://github.com/golang/appengine where things are cleaned up in that version of the API.  So hopefully the regular version too will be cleaned up.